# Is there an Search Location in mapbox ? To finding distance between the two places like google map

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox-android

I am trying to find distance between two places by searching the place name how to do it with mapbox in unity 3d

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code what you have done yet

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 Distance(Double[], Double[])
```

Find the squared *distance* between two **n-dimensional** points.

**Declaration:**

```
public double Distance(double[] p1, double[] p2)
```

**Parameters:**

```
System.Double[] p1
```

*The first point.*

```
System.Double[] p2
```

*The second point.*

**Returns:**
`System.Double`, The n-dimensional squared distance.

**Implements**

```
DistanceFunctions.Distance(Double[], Double[])
```